# Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._VariantDataset'> to Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just found a code from github, and want to test and learn the code.
but when I run the code it show up "Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops._VariantDataset'> to Tensor."
could some one can help me?
thanks!

(https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33487)
here is the code:

```
from time import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, Bidirectional, Conv1D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# to disable Eager in 2.0:  tf.enable_eager_execution()
# to enable Eager in 1.14: tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

def timeit(func, iterations, *args):
    t0 = time()
    for _ in range(iterations):
        func(*args)
    print("Time/iter: %.4f sec" % ((time() - t0) / iterations))

def make_small_model(batch_shape):
    ipt   = Input(batch_shape=batch_shape)
    x     = Conv1D(128, 400, strides=4, padding='same')(ipt)
    x     = Flatten()(x)
    x     = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x     = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
    out   = Dense(1,  activation='sigmoid')(x)
    model = Model(ipt, out)
    model.compile(Adam(lr=1e-4), 'binary_crossentropy')
    return model

def make_medium_model(batch_shape):
    ipt   = Input(batch_shape=batch_shape)
    x     = Bidirectional(LSTM(512, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))(ipt)
    x     = LSTM(512, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(x)
    x     = Conv1D(128, 400, strides=4, padding='same')(x)
    x     = Flatten()(x)
    x     = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
    x     = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x     = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    x     = Dense(64,  activation='relu')(x)
    out   = Dense(1,  activation='sigmoid')(x)
    model = Model(ipt, out)
    model.compile(Adam(lr=1e-4), 'binary_crossentropy')
    return model

def make_data(batch_shape, n_batches):
    data = np.random.randn(n_batches, *batch_shape),
    trgt = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n_batches, batch_shape[0], 1))
    return tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data, trgt))

batch_shape = (32, 400, 16)
data = make_data(batch_shape, n_batches=10)

model = make_medium_model(batch_shape)  # OR change to make_small_model
model.train_on_batch(data.take(1))
timeit(lambda: model.fit(data, steps_per_epoch=10), 10)
```

Comment: Any update on this?